# Programmatically change widget title in IBM Connections

Tags: ibm-connections

I'am trying to programmatically change a widget title in Connections. I use the following REST end-point:
/communities/service/atom/community/widgets?communityUuid=xyz&widgetInstanceId=xyz
Using the following PUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
   <title type="text">Bestandjes</title>
   <category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="widget">
   </category>
   <snx:widgetDefId>Files</snx:widgetDefId>
   <snx:widgetInstanceId>Wfa656aa9103e_41d2_a7fc_44e84d642aa4</snx:widgetInstanceId>
   <snx:hidden>false</snx:hidden>
   <snx:location>col2</snx:location>
</entry>
```

With the WidgetInstanceId and communityID as a parameter. After the PUT is being executed, no error did occur but the title stays the same. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get this working by adding the following:

```
<snx:customTitle>TestChangeBookmarks</snx:customTitle>
```

i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
<title type="text">Bookmarks</title>
<category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="widget">
</category>
<snx:customTitle>TestChangeBookmarks</snx:customTitle>
<snx:widgetInstanceId>W127627423458_49a0_bba1_af9bbf24d395</snx:widgetInstanceId>
<snx:hidden>false</snx:hidden>
<snx:location>col2</snx:location>
</entry>
```

*Note the  element should contain the current title of the widget before making changes.

*Note  is ignored for PUT request, therefore it is not needed.

More information on the widget entry elements can be found here:

[https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+5.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_community_widgets_ic50&content=apicontent](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%205.0%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_community_widgets_ic50&content=apicontent)

[Updated Community Widget Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMnGt.jpg)